# jQuery - Toggle div when clicking on h3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just finished a website for my boss, and now he decided that he wants me to hide everything on the page and just show the content when the user clicks on a specific text of the page. (In this case, the h3's).

```
<div id="container-geral" class="container" style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <h4>Clique no nome do gráfico para mostrá-lo!</h4>
    <!-- Gráfico com o numero de estudantes matriculados em abril de 2016 por regional -->
    <div class="row">
        <h3 class="text-center">Número de estudantes matriculados em abril de <?php echo $anoSelecionadoPOST ?> por regional</h3>
        <canvas id="myChart1" style="width: 900px; height: 500px; display: none;" ></canvas>
        <script>
            var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart1");
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: ["Goiânia", "Jataí", "Catalão", "Goiás", "Total"],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Número de estudantes',
                        data: [<?php
                $sql = "SELECT COUNT(Estudante) AS count FROM `$anoSelecionadoPOST` WHERE municipio=";
                chartData($arrayUnidades, $sql);
                ?>],
                <?php
                opcoesGrafico();
                ?>;
        </script>
    </div>
(...) //from now on, I have basically the same struct (as the one on the div with the class row above) over and over again.
</div>
```

So, what I need is a jQuery or javaScript function to hide and show the  element when the user clicks on the H3 text.

Thanks everyone! =)

EDIT:
This is what I have done:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $(".row").each(function() {
                    $("h3").click(function(){ 
                        $(this).next("canvas").toggle();
                    });
                });
            });
```

The problem is that it hides and show every canvas on the page, and not just the one following the h3 tag.

Comment: Clicking the `<h3>` should toggle the next `<canvas>` sibling element? If you toggle the `<div>` you won't be able to re-show it, since the `<h3>` will also be hidden.

Comment: Show us what you've tried to do, we're not here to write complete code for you

Comment: Yes, @DavidThomas when clicking the <h3> it should toggle the next <canvas> sibling element.

Comment: I think your code should work .

check this [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/1CPTYT6nrUZ8gsF8xRzH?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

you can bind an event with jQuery with the "on" function.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Then you can use the "hide" and "show" function in the callback.

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

http://api.jquery.com/show/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

> toggle(): Display or hide the matched elements.

```
$('h3').on('click', function(){ 
     $(yourElement).toggle();   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want a construct like this :

```
<h3>Something</h3>
<div class="show-h3">
    content
</div>
```

And then manipulate this with jQuery as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.show-h3').hide();

  $('h3').click(function() {
    if ($(this).next('div.show-h3').css('display') == "none") {
      $(this).next('div.show-h3').fadeIn();
    } else {
      $(this).next('div.show-h3').fadeOut();
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Something 1</h3>
<div class="show-h3">
  Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>
</div>
<h3>Something 2</h3>
<div class="show-h3">
  Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>
</div>
<h3>Something 3</h3>
<div class="show-h3">
  Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>
</div>
<h3>Something 4</h3>
<div class="show-h3">
  Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>
</div>
<h3>Something 5</h3>
<div class="show-h3">
  Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>
</div>
<h3>Something 6</h3>
<div class="show-h3">
  Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>
</div>
<h3>Something 7</h3>
<div class="show-h3">
  Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>
</div>
<h3>Something 8</h3>
<div class="show-h3">
  Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>Some content
  <br>
</div>
```